# Problemas com else if no servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Estou mexendo com jsp. No meu `servlet` tenho `if` e `else if` e os dois enviam para a mesma página, só que com valores diferentes. Porém, quando entra na opção do `if`(mostra o resultado) e então quando volta a página e tenta a opção do `else if`, não funciona. Como posso solucionar isso?
Como exemplo:

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
if (/*condicao*/) {
    arquivo.tarefa1 = 0;
    request.getSession().setAttribute("arquivo", arquivo);
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");
}
else {
    arquivo.tarefa2 = 1;
    request.getSession().setAttribute("arquivo", arquivo);
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");         
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```

No caso, não coloquei os valores diferentes que passo para a página.. mas o necessário acredito que seja isso. 
Quando executado e entra na opção do `if` e depois voltar a página e entrar na opção do `else` ele não funciona.
O request passa arquivo, um objeto que criei.

Comment: Amigo, releia a sua pergunta com calma e pense bem na quantidade de código que você nos deu para que possamos saber o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar diferentes atributos na requisição e ler eles de volta no JSP:

```java
if (/*condicao*/) {
    request.setAttribute("caminhoTomado", "if");
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");
}
else {
    request.setAttribute("caminhoTomado", "else");
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");         
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Eu já uso o request.setAttribute. Dei uma atualizada no código a cima.

Comment: Você está setando sempre a mesma coisa tanto no if quanto no else. Aqui na minha resposta eu estou setando coisas diferentes.

Comment: sim, o problema que dentro do if e do else eu preciso mudar alguns valores do objeto arquivo.

Comment: @Pacíficão E porque isso é um problema? Você não pode usar um `<c:if test="${requestScope.arquivo.tarefa1 == 0}">...</c:if>` ou coisa assim?

Comment: não sei se entendi direito o que disse.. mas preciso que isso esteja no servlet(java) e preciso das condições. Como disse na pergunta, cada botão é onde ele entra na condição. E caso o usuario volte a pagina e clique em outra opção, está dando problema.

Comment: Primeiro, você não pode ou não quer mexer no JSP? Segundo, isso só acontece quando o usuário escolhe a opção 1 na primeira vez e a opção 2 na segunda, correto? E se o usuário escolher a opção 2 na primeira vez e a 1 na segunda?

Comment: por outros motivos preciso que seja no servlet. E não.. sao 4 opções, não importa qual a ordem. A primeira opção escolhida funciona, as seguintes não.

Comment: @Pacíficão Se a primeira funciona e as demais não, então o seu problema provavelmente está no session ou no uso de variáveis globais no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

`insira o código aqui`Veja o que você esta fazendo:

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
if (/*condicao*/) {
    arquivo.tarefa1 = 0;
    request.getSession().setAttribute("arquivo", arquivo);
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");
}
else {
    arquivo.tarefa2 = 1;
    request.getSession().setAttribute("arquivo", arquivo);
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta1.jsp");         
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Aqui,

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("arquivo", arquivo);
```

Você torna possível usar o objeto "arquivo" por request no seu jsp resposta1.jsp.

Com respeito ao

```
arquivo.tarefa1 = 0;

arquivo.tarefa2 = 1;
```

Obs.: tarefa1 e tarefa2 são atributos públicos? public tarefa1.....

Senão, deveria ser arquivo.setTarefa1(0) ao invés de arquivo.tarefa1 = 0;

Você esta indicando que o atributo tarefa1 do objeto  arquvo tem valor 1 e não deu valor ao atributo tarefa2.

Quando chegar no seu jsp, não saberá onde entrou a condicional. Se no if ou se no else. Ao menos que verifique no jsp entre tarefa1 e tarefa2 quem não esta vazio.

Entendeu?