# Problema com sessão no servet

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlet

Tenho a *saida.jsp*. É minha página que dependendo da opção escolhida pelo usuário, ela é montada de uma maneira. Tenho duas opções pro usuário *verbos* e *adverbios*.
Caso o usuário clique na opção *verbos* ele será redirecionado para a pagina *saida.jsp* e ela será montada de uma forma. O mesmo vale para a opção *adverbios*.
O meu problema é quando o usuário seleciona a opção *verbos*, em seguida ele volta a página e seleciona a opção *adverbios*. Quando isso acontece, a página *adverbios* aparece como se fosse a de *verbos*.
Já procurei a respeito, me disseram que é erro de sesssão, mas não sou muito entendedor de sessão.

```
if(str.equals("verbos")){
            extrair = Extrair.verbos();
            verbos.contVerb = extrair.contverb;
            request.getSession().setAttribute("verbos", verbos);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saida.jsp");
}
else if(str.equals("adverbios")){
            extrair = Extrair.adverbios();
            adverbios.contAdv = extrair.contadv;
            request.getSession().setAttribute("adverbios", adverbios);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saida.jsp");
}
```

Esse é o tratamento que disse. Não sei como mexer com sessão, alguém poderia me esclarecer?

Comment: `Extrair.();` - isso não compila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está colocando os atributos na sessão, mas um não está limpando o outro. Ao acessar as duas páginas, ambos os atributos "adverbios" e "verbos" terão sido setados na sessão e ambos serão visíveis no `saida.jsp`, pois a requisição vai receber a sessão do jeito que a requisição anterior a deixou.

A solução é remover o atributo indesejado:

```java
if(str.equals("verbos")){
        extrair = Extrair.verbos();
        verbos.contVerb = extrair.contverb;
        request.getSession().setAttribute("verbos", verbos);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("adverbios", null); // Remove o "adverbios".
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saida.jsp");
}
else if(str.equals("adverbios")){
        extrair = Extrair.adverbios();
        adverbios.contAdv = extrair.contadv;
        request.getSession().setAttribute("adverbios", adverbios);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("verbos", null); // Remove o "verbos".
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("saida.jsp");
}
```

Aliás, vejo que isso é um remake [dessa sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47086/problemas-com-else-if-no-servlet). Como você elaborou esta daqui de uma forma bem melhor, ficou bem mais fácil de responder. :)

Comment: isso realmente funcionou para o problema reportado. Mas agora quando ele carrega a segunda opção, fica em branco.. não é passado os valores que estão no objeto.

Comment: @Pacíficão Porque você usa a variável "verbos" no bloco dos advérbios?

Comment: foi sem querer aquilo, ja arrumei. Estava errado só ake, meu codigo ta certo.

Comment: @Pacíficão Bem, seja lá o que for que ainda esteja errado agora, não parece estar neste trecho de código que você postou. Como está o JSP? De onde você obtém a variável `str`?

Comment: aí que está o problema. quando coloco um `sout` ele mostra na IDE o `str` correto. Ele reconhece, mas quando passa pra saida.jsp ele nao consegue pegar o conteudo do objeto.

Comment: @Pacíficão Então, o que tem dentro do JSP afinal?